# mvn download package files into current directory

Tags: maven, maven-3

can anybody please help why mvn command always download dependancy files into current directory? It should be stored into M2_HOME right?

I have tried

```
mvn package
mvn help:system
```

$M2_HOME has been set correctly

```
C:\> mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\Users\Documents\bin\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_252, vendor: Azul Systems, Inc., runtime: C:\Users\Documents\bin\Zulu\zulu-8\jre
Default locale: en_SG, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: There should be no `M2_HOME` variable being set because it's not needed. You should have your executable in your `PATH` which is enough. Only the `JAVA_HOME` should point to your JDK correctly. The location where the downloaded files (from central) are stored is by default `$HOME/.m2/repository` this can be changed if really needed by using a `settings.xml` which needs to be located in `$HOME/.m2`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@khmarbaise, thank you for your reply. I tried to follow your advice but problem persists.

First I notice my $HOME variable is not set but $JAVA_HOME is good

So I set up $HOME variable and restarted command prompt but result is still same - 'mvn package' still downloads packages to current working directory instead of $HOME/.m2/repository.

Secondly I checked $HOME/.m2/settings.xml file. Do you see any issues below?

```
<settings
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <localRepository/>
    <interactiveMode/>
    <usePluginRegistry/>
    <offline/>
    <pluginGroups/>
    <servers/>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>xxx-maven</id>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            <name>xxx maven repo</name>            <url>https://xxx/nexus/repository/repo/</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles/>
    <activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

Comment: $HOME is a placeholder for your home directory. Remove the entry `<localRepository/>` in your settings.xml file... and retry and remove all the empty entries except the one you have configured for nexus repo..

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise, it is almost correct. I somehow have to hardcode localRepository. Please repost your comment as a separate answer so that I can mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: Why do you need to "hard code" local repository? The default is $HOME/.m2/repository which fits more or less all the time...(except in a CI environment) where it is controlled by the CI solution...

Comment: I don't know why, honestly speaking. When I remove local repository the downloaded packages are still in current directory. @khmarbaise

Comment: Than there is something weird in your setup or in your project pom files...

Answer (score -1):

M2_HOME is usually set as an environment variable. You can do the following to check its value.

```
  echo $M2_HOME
```

Now since it seems like on Windows, I think the right command would be:

```
  echo %M2_HOME%
```

The packages are usually available under `%M2_HOME%/repository`